# Implement continuous tracking of vehicles and find the nearest vehicle using node.js

Tags: node.js, postgis

I am trying to implement a service where a fleet of vehicles is tracked continuously.To do this I plan to use POSTGIS as the database where the location of those vehicles is updated frequently/periodically.
When a user makes a request I would like to find the closest vehicle to the user.
I am planning to use POSTGIS with node.js.

Is it a good way to approach this problem or is there any other database that can be used for such 'real time' needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MONGODb database instead of POSTGIS.It provides better support for storing lat long of vehicles and have adequate support for geoquery which can find the distance between two geolocations.You can refer to these links for better clarification :

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/

Comment: can mongodb be used for 'real time' requirement as above?

Comment: since you say that one is "better" than the other, why don't you give a bit of explanation. PostGIS seems perfectly adequate for this task